# Creating and using System.Drawing.Bitmap in C++/CLI

Tags: c#, c++-cli, gdi+

I am trying to accomplish the following in C++/CLI.

I have a native class that constructs the content of an image (bitmap):

```
unsigned char* NativeClass:GetBitmapBits(void)
```

I want to use this data to create a managed System.Drawing.Bitmap. My first thought is to use the constructor:

```
Bitmap(
int width, 
int height, 
int stride, 
PixelFormat format, 
IntPtr scan0
)
```

I had this somewhat working, but am now running into issues where later usage of this Bitmap results in a first chance exception System.AccessViolationException in System.Drawing. I suspect that the problem is that I am not properly managing the transition of the unmanaged bitmaps bits (returned by the native method) to passing it into the managed Bitmap constructor.

How should I be taking the native pointer from the first function and preparing it (e.g. do I need to use interior_ptr or pin_ptr?) and passing it to the Bitmap constructor that expects an IntPtr?

edit: To elaborate, here is my naive attempt at doing this:

```
virtual void OnPaint(PaintEventargs^ e) override
{
...
   unsigned char* bits = nativeClassObj->getBitmapBits();

   gcnew Bitmap(width, height, stride, PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb, (IntPtr)bits);

   e->Graphics->DrawImage((System::Drawing::Image^)managedBitmap,0,0);
...
}
```

.. and the result (I get a 'Red X' in the drawing window):

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
```

Comment: Nothing special is needed, it wants a pointer to unmanaged memory.  Obvious failure modes are not guessing the Bitmap constructor arguments correctly and not keeping the pointer stable while the bitmap is in use.  There is no obvious way to tell that it is no longer in use.

Comment: @HansPassant The latter may be an issue - can you direct me towards how to keep the pointer stable? I'm new to C++/CLI.

Comment: I tried using pin_ptr for the native pointer, but no luck.

Comment: It depends on the API of your native C++ class. The pointer to the bits must be valid for the whole lifetime of the Bitmap; the Bitmap does not make its own copy of the image data.